# Parse text data organized by "tab-levels"

Tags: python, json, text

I have data in a text-file where the "tab-level" indicates relation:

```
0
    A
        X
        Y
        Z
    B
        M
        N
        O
```

I am using python to read this file, and want to parse the data into a structure.  The structure should resemble a regular python/json object:

```
{
0: {
   A: [ X, Y, Z ]  ,      
   B: [ M, N, O ]      
   }
}
```

Is there an easy way to iterate over a text file and parse data by "tab-level"?

Comment: One question the data structure you provided not correct. Because if there are more than   2 indentations then it should be ` A: { {X: P}, Y, Z }  ,   ...` which is not a valid data structure because set should contain `hashable` datatypes. I think you mean `A: [X, Y, Z]`

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I updated

Comment: B might not have children

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, the provided data structure is not correct.
Here is my approach.

Here I am considering **space**, not **tab** since I was making the regex in https://regex101.com/ and tab was not doing anything :p.  But you just need to change the regular expression and the constant value 4.

**first**: Determine the indentation level and the value
**second**: Create tree from them
**third**: Recursively generate the data structure from the tree

```py
import re

s = """0
    A
        X
            Third_Level
        Y
        Z
    B
        M
        N
        O
"""

# asuming indentation level will be multiple of 4
l = [(len(space), character) for space, character in re.findall(r'^((?:\s{4})*)([^\s]+)', s, re.MULTILINE)]

# defining the node class
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.children = []

# now creating the tree        
root = None
node_dict = {}
for i in l:
    if(i[0] == 0): # special case root node
        root = Node(i[1])
        node_dict[i[0]] = root
    else:
        parent = i[0] - 4
        node = Node(i[1])
        node_dict[parent].children.append(node)
        node_dict[i[0]] = node
        
# defining the recursive funtion to generate the op from tree        
def construct(r):
    if(len(r.children) == 0):
        return r.value
    else:
        val = []
        for each_child in r.children:
            val.append(construct(each_child))
        return {r.value: val if len(val) > 1 else val[0]}
        
        
            
construct(root)
```

```
{'0': [{'A': [{'X': 'Third_Level'}, 'Y', 'Z']}, {'B': ['M', 'N', 'O']}]}
```